# How is it possible to create an information fetcher for a game like League of Legends?

Tags: c++

Basically what I'm wondering is, how could you get like a list of all mobs, champions their hp, mana etc with programming? I know this is possible because it has been done before but I just can't see how you would be able to do this. Is looking in the assembler code necessary or can you do it in some other way? I'm mostly wondering about the theory behind it. (Using C++ if that helps anything at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such things are usually done using crawling (e.g. retrieving the data from the web pages provided by Riot Games; might be partially outdated) or using reverse engineering to get this data from the game client's files (might not contain everything). In either way you'd get datasets which you'll have to read or interpret (look for values or replicate the way the game client reads and interprets the data).

I'm not sure whether there are some tools or APIs released somewhere, at least I haven't heard of anything officially supported or endorsed; most of this is essentially in a gray zone usage wise.